# How can I re-write this while loop using nested for loops?

Tags: python

I followed an algorithm with a `while` loop, but one of the parameters of the question was that I use nested for loops, and I'm not sure how to do that.

This is the `while` loop:

```
i = len(lst)
while i > 0:
    big = lst.index(max(lst[0:i]))
    lst[big], lst[i-1] = lst[i-1], lst[big]
    i = i - 1
    return lst
```

This is the question it's answering:

Input: `[5,1,7,3]`

First, find the largest number, which is `7`.
Swap it and the number currently at the end of the list, which is `3`. Now we have: `[5,1,3,7]`
Now, find the largest number, not including the `7`, which is `5`.
Swap it and the second to last number, which is `3`. Now we have: `[3,1,5,7]`.
Now, find the third largest number (excluding the first two), which is `3`.
Swap it and the third to last number, which is `1`.

Output: `[1, 3, 5, 7]`

Comment: What is the initial value of `i`?

Comment: please explain what your code does

Comment: It'll be better if you can paste the actual question as well here

Comment: its the selection sort in reverse order of iteration that is going from N-> 0 instead of going from 0 -> N , Id say just google it  :-)

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing in the algorithm is a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). And here's your second solution which you asked (nested `for` loops):

```
def insertion_sort(arr):
    l = len(arr)
    for i in range(l-1, -1, -1):
        m = -10000 # it should be lower than min(arr)
        idx = -1
        for key, val in enumerate(arr[:i+1]):
            if m < val:
                m = val
                idx = key
        if idx != -1:
            arr[i], arr[idx] = arr[idx], arr[i]
    return arr
```

And a quick test:

```
arr = list(range(10))[::-1]
print(arr)
# prints [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
result = insertion_sort(arr)
print(result)
# prints [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a (rather slow) sorting algorithm - namely bubble sort. It's iterating from the end of the list `lst`. Then it's searching for the maximum value in the first `n-1` elements, and swapping them with the end. It will, however, fail, if the maximum value is already at the end, because then it will automatically swap the `max(n-1)` with the `n` value. You'll need to add a check for this.

So from a first look, I'm not sure if `i` is defined before, but let's assume it's defined at the length of the list `lst`, as it seems to be. So let's start with the outer loop - as have a while loop that looks like it's counting down from `i` to 0. This is the opposite of an increasing for-loop, so we can create a reserved range:

```
rev_range = range(0,len(lst))
rev_range.reverse() 
for j in rev_range:
    # perform the sort
```

We now have the outer loop for the counting-down while loop. The sort itself iterates forward until it finds the maximum. This is a forward for loop.

```
# sorting
max_val_so_far_index=lst[j]
# lst[:j-1] gets the first j-1 elements of the list
for k in lst[:j-1]:
    if lst[k] > lst[max_val_so_far_index]:
        max_val_so_far_index = k
# now we have the index of the maximum value
# swap
temp = lst[j]
lst[j] = lst[max_val_so_far_index]
lst[max_val_so_far_index]=temp
```

Let's put the two components together to get:

```
rev_range = range(0,len(lst))
rev_range.reverse() 
for j in rev_range:
    # perform the sort
    # sorting
    #print j
    max_val_so_far_index=j

    # get the first j items
    for k in range(j):
        if lst[k] > lst[max_val_so_far_index]:
            max_val_so_far_index = k
    # now we have the index of the maximum value
    # swap
    temp = lst[j]
    lst[j] = lst[max_val_so_far_index]
    lst[max_val_so_far_index]=temp
```

At the end `lst` is sorted.

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm in the question is just another form of a [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). The original algorithm uses two nested for loops. You can find a good explaination [here](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheBubbleSort.html).